# Zariski closure of $\text{Spec}\; k[x,y]/(y^2-(x-a)(x-b))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding an exercise in algebraic geometry. It says:

> Consider a characteristic $0$ field $k$ and the scheme $X=\text{Spec}\; k[x,y]/(y^2-(x-a)(x-b))\subseteq\mathbb{A}_k^2$. Let $\bar{X}$ be the Zariski closure of $X$. When is $X$ smooth? When is $\bar X$?

Isn't $X$ always Zariski closed? The surjection from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,y]/(y^2-(x-a)(x-b))$ should induce a closed immersion of schemes. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps they mean closure in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$.

Comment: That's almost certainly it. Thank you. If you want, you can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps they mean the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$. However, what exactly this means in scheme theory is a bit unclear if $X$ is not reduced. In that case, it may be more appropriate to consider the scheme-theoretic closure.